# Isn't OOD in PHP double storing what is in MySQL resourcefully wasteful?

Tags: php, mysql

My question is: if I create objects in PHP based on the data in MySQL, aren't I double storing the data and therefore wasting resources and slowing down my application?

1. Do people just do this for the sake of caching the MySQL data as objects which allows for faster access because a user isn't querying the database every time they switch to a new product?
2. Do they just do it for less complex code?
3. What's the appropriate way to handle this in a small MVC? i.e. at the beginning of a session, should the model create an array of all the products? should there never be an array of all products and just ask the database everytime and convert this data into a new Product object every time?

If you care to, you can read on for why I'm asking...

I get that this doesn't really matter for the size of my application, but I'd like to start it right.
I have a basic little MVC I made and a database of items that we'll call products. Just trying to decide if/when/where to go from MySQL data to PHP objects for my convenience.

This is how my file tree looks like :

```
root
    controller
        Controller.php
    model
        Model.php
        Product.php
    view
        Products.php
        Product.php
    index.php
```

Here is the relevant code :

```
// Controller.php
if (!isset($_GET['product'])) {
    - getProducts() && include view/Products
} else {
    - getProduct('product') && include view/Product
}

// Model.php
getProducts() {
    while($row = $stmt->fetch_assoc()) {
        $array[$i] = new Product($row["id"], $row["name"], $row["price"]);
        $i++;
    }
    return $array;
}
getProduct($id) {
    $allProducts = $this->getProducts();
    return $allProducts[$id];
}

// Products view
<?php foreach ($products as $product): ?>
    display $product->id and $product->name
<?php endforeach; ?>

// Product view
display $product->name and $product->description and $product->price ...
```

Comment: i don't get it. how do you expect to use data in a database without first bringing it into memory (i.e. storing it in a variable as an object or an array)?

Comment: I'm not really sure what you're asking. Is this about why to create classes and object representations of data in the database...?

Answer (score 3):

It does technically duplicate the data in the database into memory, but in the same way that reading a menu at a restaurant duplicates the menu items into your own memory. There is no way to utilize or process data from a database *without* reading it into memory for the script doing that uses the data, just as there is no way to order something from a menu without briefly holding it in your own memory. And, just as you probably can't remember most of the menu by the end of the meal - forgotten after you no longer need it - PHP will not hold anything in memory after the script finishes executing, as the entire VM is destroyed after a script ends.

It's a good idea not to read data into memory that you don't need - for example, look up the one user record you need, not the entire users table. You'll have to do your own benchmarking to assess your own specific scenario, but generally speaking, you're better off doing repeated, small queries (with WHERE clauses that use good indexes) to retrieve only the data you need, rather than doing large queries to retrieve a lot of data that you may or may not need.

Answer (score 2):

You have a major misconception. PHP is **NOT** a daemon environment - in other words, your objects are not stored or shared between client instances unless you are using a very specific set-up to do so. By default, PHP is functional - it will go from start to finish through instructions and when it is done, it ends and shuts itself down.

This means that your product, say, ID 4 in your DB, is only ever used while it is in PHP memory. By default, the moment something runs out of references, PHP unsets it. So, suppose you have your product model instance, you use it, then you unset it - voila, gone from memory.

Take your code, for instance. On the controller, you're calling `getProduct`. The product is found, returned, and the moment the controller is done, it is unset. This led to one SQL query. It is a form of double storage, but not in any way more demanding than just using old procedural MySQL code style.

A model itself, by itself, is a *representation* of your data. It allows you to abstract away all the database structure into a form that makes sense and is more logical, and more importantly, easy to cache, transfer and retrieve. It is not a second form of storage. Think of it as a "translation".

I guess the answers from above:

1. It enables caching, but this is a nice side-effect. They mostly do it for maintainability, code readability and to easily and nicely use dependency injection-esque formats for arguments
2. Yes. Less complex, easier to maintain, easier to use, easier to expand
3. Your model should have a getter, or you should make a locator for your models. This is the same purpose - you give it an ID, it gives you back the model by querying the DB or the cache engine that you would prefer to use. If you're unsure of how to build this, use already-made tools. Most modern frameworks have this - Laravel and Symfony are two very good examples of how things **should** be done.

Finally, could you explain to me one thing: how do you plan on getting data from MySQL without storing it in memory? PHP does not possess telepathy.

Comment: Calling PHP "functional" is quite a debatable use of the term... :)

Comment: By that I meant - connect to my DB, print data to screen, close the DB, as opposed to connect to my DB, create PHP object (which I believed to be stored in memory), close the DB, then print from the object whenever.

Comment: @caleb.breckon: The cost of closing your DB connection is non-trivial. This is something my boss discovered. You want to keep it open - best case scenario, you get to re-use it. Worst case scenario, PHP closes it down **AFTER** your page is rendered. win-win all around.

Comment: @deceze: I know. Guilty as charged.

Comment: @caleb.breckon: this answer from DBA might help you understand what I meant in my last comment - http://dba.stackexchange.com/a/16981